# How can I determine the location of the current user's Documents folder from a Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, windows-libraries

I know I could use `%userprofile%\Documents`, but this only works if the Documents folder is still in the default location.  I am looking for something that works even if the user has changed the location (i.e., from the Location tab in Documents Properties.)

Comment: Batch does not usually Search . Why not just find the folder structure with Windows Search?

Comment: @John I have a batch script I wrote that performs a series of tasks -- one of them happens to involve checking whether a file exists in the documents folder, and I'd like to update this step so it works on machines where the location of Documents has been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a way that works for me:

```
for /f usebackq %%a in (
    `powershell -command "[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Personal')"`
) do (set "docs_folder=%%a")
echo %docs_folder%
```

Comment: If you are satisfied, why not accept it as answer.

Comment: Calling powershell to do something in a batch file is kind of silly. Why not write the whole thing in powershell.

Comment: @Appleoddity Well, in my case, I actually had already written a longer batch script that did a bunch of other things, and I just wanted to fix one part that depended on the location of the Documents folder.  So re-writing the whole thing in PowerShell didn't seem worth it.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta I would have, but apparently the site makes you wait two days before accepting an answer to your own question.

Comment: @TimGoodman Oh Ok! Didn't know that.

Answer (score 5):

Why not read this information where it is registered directly in the Windows registry:

**[`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`](https://www.repairwin.com/change-personal-folders-location-using-registry-windows-8-7-vista/)**

[image]

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_Key_HKCU_Path=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
set "_Folders_Refer={374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B},Documments,Desktop,Favorites,My Music,My Pictures,My Video,Personal,Programs,Start Menu,Startup"

(for %%i in ("!_Folders_Refer:,=","!")do call :^) %%~i) && endlocal && goto :EOF

:^)
for /f tokens^=3* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%reg.exe query "!_Key_HKCU_Path!"^|find/i "%~1"
')do <con: set "_user_path=%%i%%j" && cmd /v/c "echo\!_user_path:REG_EXPAND_SZ=! && exit /b"
```

- Outputs results:

```all-bat
C:\Users\ecker\Downloads
C:\Users\ecker\Desktop
C:\Users\ecker\Favorites
C:\Users\ecker\Music
C:\Users\ecker\Pictures
C:\Users\ecker\Videos
C:\Users\ecker\Music
C:\Users\ecker\Pictures
C:\Users\ecker\Videos
C:\Users\ecker\Music
C:\Users\ecker\Pictures
C:\Users\ecker\Videos
C:\Users\ecker\Documents
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup
```

[image]

---

For just Personal/Documents folder:

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"

for /f tokens^=3 %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%reg.exe query "!_Key!"^|find/i "Personal"')do <con: call set "_docs_folder=%%~i"

if exist "!_docs_folder!\My_File.docx" (
     echo\!_docs_folder!\My_File.docx 
     echo\File exist
   ) else (
     echo\!_docs_folder!\My_File.docx 
     echo\File do not exist
   )
   
endlocal && goto :EOF
```

- Output results:

```all-bat
C:\Users\ecker\Documents
```

**Obs.: 1** Use **`<con: call`** with **`set "_docs_folder=%%~i"`** to expand the full path in variable **`%%~i`** (**`%UserProfile%\Documents`**) to **`C:\Users\ecker\Documents`**

**Obs.: 2** Your code (**[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** with **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**) works very well (*for username/folder without space*), and it can also be written that way:

```all-bat
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('powershell -co [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Personal'^)
')do set "docs_folder=%%a" & if exist "%docs_folder%\*.*" echo\"%docs_folder%\*.*"
```

[image]

Consider using all (`*`) tokens, because `tokens^=*` ensures that all characters in the loop variable (`%%i`) are taken to compose the value in the variable, including the standard delimiters, such as space (for example), and if the username contains any, without `tokens^=*`, only the first token will actually be used (by default), and in its output/variable will be missing additional characters.

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10, better to use PowerShell:

You can query the Registry:

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders').Personal

     - or -

$Key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'
(gp $Key).Personal
```

Or query the Shell:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace("shell:Personal").Self.Path
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders').Personal
C:\Users\keith\Documents
PS C:\>
PS C:\> (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace("shell:Personal").Self.Path
C:\Users\keith\Documents
PS C:\>
```

Answer (score -1):

@Tim

Your browser(s) store your default downloads location. For example, in Chrome v83, I can find my downoads folder by searching in... **C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences**

Look for **"default_directory"** (including the double quotes).

In my case, my default downloads location is **E:\DNLDS** and I found the following string in my **Preferences** file:

**"default_directory":"E:\DNLDS"**

**Note:** in the line above, forum software removed the double backslash from my answer. The actual string found in **Preferences** file contains two backslash symbols after the disk name (E) as in...

`"default_directory":"E:\\DNLDS"`

Other browsers use different locations for preferences or profiles, but they all must store the target location for files you download from the web.

Be aware that some people define multiple profiles on a given PC. Your batch file  may need to download a test file (with a unique name) and search all the default locations to determine which one is the current default. Also, some people define different default downloads locations in different browsers on the same PC. IOW, some users have multiple default downloads locations.